# Status bar not the same color as the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios11, xcode9, swift4, uistatusbar

I have a Navigation Controller, where I am coloring my navigation bar with some color, and I want the status bar (which shows the carrier, wifi symbol, etc) to use the same color.

So in `Info.plist`, I have set `View controller-based status bar appearance equal` to `NO`. And in the `Target > Deployment Info` I set the `Status Bar Style > Light`:

[image]

I can see that the status bar is now indeed using the "light" style as the text is light/white. But the status bar background is still not the same as the Navigation bar as seen below. How can I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You have to use like this :

```
if let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
}
```

If you want to change the status bar color all over the app, use it in `appdelegate->didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Or if you want to change for any particular screen, then call it in the particular `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: It works, but I am not sure if this is the optimal solution. When I change the status bar style to "light", it should automatically assume the color of the Navigation Bar, right?

Comment: @rgamber, did you find a more optimal solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Nothing else seems to work, so temporarily resorted to this. If you find any other way, please post it here!